# .NET Data loading optimization

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, async-await

I have seen multiple threads talking about similar problems, but none of them explain my situation or explain how to solve that problem properly.

The current Problem I am facing is that I have a DataGridView, which loads in Data from a SQLite Database asynchronously, but takes too long.

The way Data is added in the SQLite Database is by downloading a JSON file, deserializing it and then adding the deserialized file as class in a Table.

Currently there are 20 rows in the Database and it consists of 8 values, e.g. ID, Name, Price..

Sounds like there is no problem, right? Now when I want to add a new player into the list, e.g.

```
// Note this is pseudo-code as my code is a little longer (like the Process of creating a Player)
// So I'll just TL;DR the code as I think this is the most crucial information.
public async void btnAddPlayer(){
 string website = "website.com/playerdata.json";
 // This gets user data, deserializes it, creates a player object and returns it.
 var player = GetUserDataFromJSON(website);  
 // This adds a Player asynchronously to the database
 await database.AddPlayer(player);
}
```

Also to note is, the JSON consists of a Table created from [UnixTime, Price]. I get the JSON by creating a HTTPWebRequest/Response and read it with a StreamReader.

(Creating WebRequest -> Getting Response ->  StreamReader -> Deserializing)

Before adding a Player, the highest price is selected, so:

```
// This is normally no function, just put it in a function to break it down separately for this purpose
public void Function(...) {
 var highestPrice = 0;
 var highestPriceDate = DateTime.MinValue;
 foreach(var price in table.Price) {
 if(price >= highestPrice) {
 highestPrice = price;
 highestPriceDate = UnixToUTC(table.UnixTime);
}
```

The problem I'm facing with the add function is that adding the Player (and making it visible in the DataGridView) takes about 1 second. The way I'm visually updating is cloning row[0] and changing its Data. The result I'm awaiting is a few ms as it is just getting data from a JSON, deserializing it, (comparing prices), adding it to the DB and adding it into the DataGridView.

Now I also have a **REFRESH** Function (**THE BIGGEST PROBLEM!**), which gets newest Data for each Player available in the SQLite Table.

Therefore I first access the Database and Get all the Players.

```
public List<Player> GetAllPlayers(){
 // To access Table and make a query
 var query = dbConnection.Table<Player>();
 allPlayers = await query.ToListAsync();
 await conn.CloseAsync();
 return allPlayers;
}
```

Then I call an async Task to Update them all, which looks like this:

```
public async Task UpdateAllPlayers() {
 var allPlayers = await database.GetAllPlayers() {
  foreach (var player in allPlayers) {
   // Boolean "true" is marking whether it is an update.
   // If it is true, it is basically the same as btnAddPlayer(), but
   // The only difference is that it does not call
   // database.AddPlayer(player);
   // It instead calls:
   // database.UpdatePlayer(player);
   await GetPlayerInfo(player.Name, player.ID, player.Type, true);
   }
  }
```

To visually update this, I clear all the rows on the DataGridView, lastly GetAllPlayers() and add all those players in a for loop by duplicating row[0] and editing it for each player.

The issue with this function is that it already took 7 seconds for only 21 Players. I think this time will increase drastically as more players are added in. So if I had ~120 Players, (which is my current goal), I'd be waiting for each update for 42 seconds. The program won't respond for those seconds, giving me doubts about it crashing etc. as well. What I await is generally a loading time from X seconds for Y Players. Realistic sounds 1 second for 20 Players, but my current result is yet far away from this.

Comment: 7 seconds for 21 players is way too much. Start looking into this method. Assume data does not change. Optimize for this case - if there is no update, then why the heckd o more processing with the data for this one player? Then consider using threads and reading multiple players at the same time. Or have a method returning them all. THis is not a code problem as much as an architecture problem and thus opinion based.

Comment: SQLite is unlikely to be the bottleneck, unless you're doing something very pessimal. Have you run a profiler to see where that time is being taken?

Comment: If there is no update on Player price, it won't update. But to check if there is an update needed, it still needs to get the Data and compare if there is a new highest Price. So there is kind of no way that there is "no update" except you do it the exact same second or same hour. Update should be called about every 6 hours and there is a guaranteed update in that timeframe so that won't fix it sadly. It is an architecture problem, I understand. I'm unsure how I can read multiple players at the same time without breaking things or skipping players. Is there a good way to do so?

Comment: @AKX I am sorry, but I have no idea how to properly run a profiler, so not really. I'm still a beginner to this and haven't made many projects like this yet.

Comment: What IDE are you working with? If you're using Visual Studio proper, it has a couple different built-in profilers. You can also just pepper your code with `Console.WriteLine`s or similar with timestamps for a lo-fi approach.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019. If I added `Console.WriteLine`, the problem is, where should I put them in mostly? I can see about 20-30 places where it might make sense, but how can I evaluate async functions with WriteLine. I think that is not possible, is it?

Comment: I'll try to not update every player individually, but instead update all at once. I think this might fix some performance issues. I'll let you know.

Comment: Tried bulks, not better at all.